# Moments and convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_n, n = 1, 2, . . .$ be a sequence of random variables such that $|X_n| \leq M$ for some constant $M > 0$. Suppose that for each $r \in N$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[X_n^r]$ exists. Prove that $X_n \rightarrow \mu$ in distribution for some probability measure $\mu$.

My approach:
Let $X_\infty \sim{\mu}$. I want to show convergence of characteristic function of $X_n$, $\Phi_{X_n}(t)$  to $\Phi_{X_\infty}(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I think I need to use the series expansion of $e^{itX_n} = 1 + \dfrac{itX_n}{1!} + + \dfrac{(itX_n)^2}{2!} + ...$, then
$E[e^{itX_n}]= 1 + \dfrac{itE[X_n]}{1!} + \dfrac{(it)^2E[X_n^2]}{2!} + ... $.

I do not know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

The expression for $\mathbb E\left[e^{itX_n}\right]$ should be justified, since it seems that you switched the expectation and an infinite sum. 
This can be justified by Fubini's theorem (for the measure $\mathbb P\otimes\nu$, where $\nu$ is the counting measure) since 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\left|\left(itX_n\right)\right|^j/j!\leqslant 
\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}|tM|^j /j!,$$
which is integrable.

Then use the dominated convergence theorem to deduce that $\mathbb E\left[e^{itX_n}\right]$ converges to $\mathbb E\left[e^{itX}\right]$.

Comment: Do I need to work with finite sum approximation of the infinite series of the exponential and then use limiting arguments?

Comment: You can, but it is not needed. The approximation is random,  but you can use Taylor's formula to control it. I suggested an approach with the series and dominated convergence, which was more in the spirit of you approach in the opening post.

Comment: Do you think I need to use Halley's selection theorem along with tightness condition to justify that $\mu$ exists. I feel in my proof I have already assumed that $\mu$ exists.